# Swift App Xib - Second ViewController - Labels not showing for 30 seconds but Buttons etc are. How can I solve?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

Swift App Xib - Second ViewController - Labels not showing for 30 seconds but Buttons and other controls showing immediately.  What could this be / how can I solve this?

Xcode 7.3.1 
Swift 2

This is happening on the device and in the simulator

---> [Video of Issue](https://youtu.be/2JMiwE0tlSY)  <-----

I present from first viewController like this:

```
 secondViewController.user = user

 self.presentViewController(secondViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Second View Controller

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ViewController did load")

        print("selected facility is: ", user?.selectedFacility)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

//    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
//        super.init(nibName: "ListViewController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
//    }


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        print("awake from nib")
    }
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewWillAppear")
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidAppear")

    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        print("viewDidDisappear")
    }
```

**UPDATE**

If I set the text in viewDidLoad the label appears at the same time as everything else.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("ListViewController did load")
        labelX.text = "heyVC"
```

Adding the outlet itself didn't change anything.  It was actually programmatically setting the text that fixed it.  I think this is a bug in IB.  I will file with apple.

Bug number is 27029176

Comment: How can anyone help you without seeing any code?

Comment: Is the label ever referenced in a view/VC file?

Comment: No the label is never referenced. I just pulled the controls onto the Xib and was testing that the present from the first viewController was working. So there is a FileOwner view controller for the second xib, but I haven't hooked the controls up to any actions in the second view controller yet. Adding the code to present and 2nd viewController code and code in second viewController

Answer (score 0):

See if you have set some custom font of label and the font file could not be found by system(like if you have deleted the file). If system font is not set in Label , try setting system font and re-run to confirm.

Comment: Not using anything custom.  I just pulled a label onto the View from the object library.  It is using System 17.0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing anything with NSURL / NSMutableURLRequest / dataTaskWithRequest?

I am experiencing exactly the same thing with the 30sec delay. When I am commenting out my code which is fetching data from an URL (with the above mentioned methods) the labels are showing instantly. When the code is executed, the labels are displayed with a delay. I guess the fetching somehow makes things asynchronous.

Not exactly a solution but maybe a starting point for further research. Please let me/us know if you have new ideas or the solution. Thanks. :-)

Comment: I am doing some async calls on the first ViewController.  Maybe somehow that is bleeding over.  But in the 2nd ViewController, I am just presenting it.  These are controls that don't have actions hooked to it yet.  I am going to set up some outlets and I will post the outcome of that.  Very odd though.  Thanks!